# create view in phpmyadmin database by php codes?

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote SQL code to create create a view in MySQL. This code in local or on my computer works correctly, but when run on remote server it doesn't work.

When I copy this code and paste in SQL place of PhpMyadmin on server it action as well as without any problem. I didn't change any section of code and only copy from php then past in phpmyadmin.

What's happening in behind of this php transaction that doesn't work on web page of server?

Full part of my views:

```
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

$view_baz1maz1="CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@ SQL SECURITY
DEFINER VIEW `baz1amz1` as select  `regvezarat`.`bazemp`.`PrsID` AS `PrsID`,
`regvezarat`.`bazemp`.`Name` AS `Name`,`regvezarat`.`bazemp`.`Family` AS `Family`,
,`regvezarat`.`bazemp`.`AccID` AS `AccID` from `regvezarat`.`bazemp`
 union select
`regvezarat`.`infemp`.`PrsID` AS `PrsID`,`regvezarat`.`infemp`.`Name` AS `Name`,
`regvezarat`.`infemp`.`Family` AS `Family`,`regvezarat`.`infemp`.`FtName` AS `FtName`,
regvezarat`.`infemp`.`NumID` AS `NumID`,`regvezarat`.`infemp`.`AccID` AS `AccID` from
`regvezarat`.`infemp`;";


if(mysqli_query($conn2,$view_baz1maz1) )
{
    $num_win+=1;
}
else
{
mysqli_error($conn2);
$num_fail+=1;
echo "baz1amz1".'<br>';
}
```

So I expect if any error occurs, the commends in the else block runs and baz1amz1 show on page for guide for me. I guess that this view runs, but it wasn't committed in DB, maybe transactions execute without any problem and in final when it want to be committed in DB, doesn't has enough privilege, from php to MySQL.
I run this code in local without any mistake and error.
If possible?

Comment: no some feature from sever and my computer different, for example in phpmyadmin of server doesn't exist privilege option in menu bar , but when create user for my DB in server, has many option for set privilege such as create view  so i am amazing

Comment: Your code has fields like "maiaandi" and "bazemp", probably a table name somewhere, do you have the same table and fields in the database you created in your remote server?

Comment: me too, thanks , @jeff, for spell my question.

Comment: as you can see, i paste this code in SQL place of phpmyadmin, it work correctly without any problem

Comment: Do you get any errors in your `php` code? does the user which you are using to connect to db in your `php` code have `create privilege`?

Comment: No. I haven't, the user that write in view code has full privilege because in MySQL it work correctly.

Comment: Probably the reason your remote phpMyAdmin doesn't show the Privilege link is that you don't have superuser permissions.

Comment: You'll have to show us a bit more code about how you use this `$view1` variable. Do you check for PHP or MySQL errors and what results does MySQL give you each step along the way?

Comment: Based on your request and suggestion i edit it and append some extra code and description, thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following part of the first line:

```
… ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@ SQL SECURITY DEFINER …
```

That is, the statement should start out as simply:

```
CREATE VIEW `baz1amz1` as select…
```

The `DEFINER=` and `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` parameters to `CREATE VIEW` require MySQL SUPER privileges, and do not affect the behavior of this view. (They are used in situations where the view needs special permissions, which doesn't appear to be the case here.)

Comment: Hello, i fallow your mention, but this problem still, as pervasively said i think maybe transaction not been committed in DB,i Copy the code that without security parameters and past in SQL statement of phpmyadmin, it works correctly. what happen in behind of run?